# Developer specific comments in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, comments

I'm hoping to learn if there is a way to:
- add comments to a class that are of a different color than the other developer on my team.
- prevent these comments from being added to version control by some type of exclusion.

Something like:

```
/**xxx
*/
```

and

```
//xxx
```

where xxx are my initials and communicate with Eclipse to change the color and exclude them from version control.

Is there anything similar to this in place, perhaps in an add-on? Any thoughts on how I could implement something like this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit for clarity: I'm the new developer on our team and have ~ 10 years of his code to get familiar with over time so I'm hoping to have my own notes in the classes (instead of in separate documents as they are now) for ease of reference.

Comment: I think the biggest problem with your idea is how to tell version control to ignore those specific lines. Why do you want these sorts of "personal" comments anyways, why wouldn't you share them with your colleagues?

Comment: It's for the other developer's classes. I need to get familiar with them and don't want to clutter our code with my notes on his classes. I have been keeping the notes separate and I think I'd really benefit from being able to see them (my own notes) in his classes as I work in them.

Comment: If you are using version control, just create two copies of the files,  a note copy and a working copy.  Your working copy is where you make all your actual changes for committing and your note copy is where you make your comments and can even use it for testing/etc.  Most version control will intelligently update it, keeping your notes.

Comment: Marshall - that was my first line of thought but there are hundreds of classes already in place and I would really prefer not to have dups of all of them - especially because I'd be forced to switch back and forth to get any work done and will probably just end up ignoring my notes copy. Is this the standard practice for maintaining specific notes on a class, or do most developers maintain separate documentation? It's crazy to think that no one has any add-ons that allow personal notes for each class that don't get committed to shared code.